# Cosmos DB - consistency level override for query - does it actually have only 3 options?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, consistency

I was reading through [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels#consistency-levels-and-throughput) and encountered this part:

| Consistency Level | Quorum Reads | Quorum Writes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Strong | Local Minority | Global Majority |
| Bounded Staleness | Local Minority | Local Majority |
| Session | Single Replica (using session token) | Local Majority |
| Consistent Prefix | Single Replica | Local Majority |
| Eventual | Single Replica | Local Majority |

So let's say I have Strong consistency set as default (for writes).
And I want to override it for some queries.
It would matter only if I select between `Strong`, `Session` and `Eventual` consistencies, because these are the ones with distinct `Quorum Reads`.
Changing between `Strong` and `Bounded Staleness` or `Consistent Prefix` and `Eventual` wouldn't matter, because it's only for reads - writes are still configured with `Strong` consistency.

Am I correct?

Edit: Though the sheer answer of [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884931/mark-brown) doesn't satisfy me, it's complete for me with the comments, so I'm marking it as a solution.
To simplify, the answer is that effectively there's actually only 2 options in query relaxation:   `Strong` and `Consistent Prefix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relaxing the consistency level on reads, including queries does have an impact but that impact is one of cost. Strong and Bounded Staleness are Local Minority. This means reads are done on two replicas and the LSN's are compared between them. If they match the data is consistent. If they do not match, the item with the greater LSN is returned as it is the most recent write.

Because data is read from two replicas, the RU/s cost is 2x that of reads from Session or weaker consistency.

It is precisely because of this reduced cost that users may want to weaken their consistency on reads. If you're building an app that does not require perfect consistency and the data can lag by a small amount of time, this is perfectly suitable and less expensive way to do it. Particularly if the queries are done with high concurrency.

It's worth pointing out that relaxing the consistency level to session will result in Consistent Prefix being used. Session consistency requires the session token which today is only scoped to a single partition key range id. Since queries can span multiple partition key range values your effective consistency level used is essentially consistent prefix.

Comment: So relaxing the consistency doesn't differ between `Strong` and ` Bounded Staleness`?

Comment: They are both minority quorum so both read from two replicas. The only difference is where the read is done. If it is in the write region both provide strong reads. If the read with Bounded Staleness is done in another region, users get Consistent Prefix. You can get consistency guarantees for Bounded Staleness by readers [Bounded Staleness consistency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels#bounded-staleness-consistency)

Comment: Ooh, so there's a difference, because this can be read in another region and can be outdated right? Even though the writes are propagated synchronously, this can still mean that the changes are committed in one region, but not in the second.

Comment: Any consistency which replicates asynchronously can have dirty reads. Only strong is synchronous so provides guarantees on global consistency as indicated in that table you referenced with writes as global majority.

Comment: Okay, but I'm asking about a situation when I have Strong consistency for writes and Bounded Staleness for reads.
Does it differ from Strong + Strong?

Comment: No, this will be the same because they both read from two replicas. There's no benefit to relaxing to Bounded Staleness. Same cost and consistency as Strong.